# Can change to navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles be animated?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I have a `MKMapView` inside a `viewController` that is the first `viewController` of a `UINavigationController`.

When this screen loads, I want to have:

`navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`

But once the user starts resizing or scrolling the `MKMapView`, I want to **animate the change** to the state where:

`navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false`

We get this style of transition animation for free when using a `UITableView`, but I'm curious if the same effect can be achieved when a `MKMapView` is the main view.